# Using ActionMailer Method in link_to Statement - Rails 3.2.3

Tags: actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to provide a link when clicked it will send an email to an admin to inform them to delete a record.  I have searched for several hours, included here but could not find any examples.

Here is the current code I would like to modify:

```
link_to "Delete your User Account?", @user, method: :delete, confirm: "You sure? This will permanently delete your account.  If you want to access our site in the future you will need to create a new account again.  Are you sure you want to delete your account?" %>
```

I would like to substitute "method: :delete" with an ActionMailer method.  I looked in the Ruby documentation at api.rubyonrails.org and other places for examples but could not find anything.

Is this something I can do without installing a gem?

Why is it so hard to find documentation with examples?  Sigh.....

Answer (score 0):

The "method: delete" is the HTTP methods passed in the headers when you call the url which is then used by the routes to find the correct controller and action.

You will want to place your method calls to the mailer in your controller where User#destroy action is.

it would be something like this.

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:user])
  if @user.desotry
    # Tell the UserMailer to send a email after destroy
    UserMailer.delete_account_email(@user).deliver
    redirect_to(@user, :notice => 'Account was successfully closed.')
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I had created a boolean field to do this.  I should have thought about that one.  I will delete the field and use your suggestion.  I'm sure it will work.

Another question:  Can you pass any field to an ActionMailer other than fields on the recipient model?  I would like to replace fields I added to the database with work fields.  Maybe I can create them like I would password & password confirmation but not have them physically on the database.

Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: You should read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

also dont forget to mark this as answered. :)

Comment: Thanks, Digital.  Please let me know how to mark something answered:)

I used the link that you suggested for the ActionMailer to write my initial mailers.  It is really good.  However I would like to see examples where mailers used passed fields from the screen.  Do you know of any examples of this or is this even possible?  All the examples are using one parameter.

Comment: There is a check box the the top right of this answer. I dont really know the answer on how to pass more then on argument I seen people say they wrap the active mails in a whole new class.

Comment: Great.  I will remember next time:)

I will keep looking about how to pass more than one argument.  I have created new fields on the database to get the info I needed on the email.  Thanks for your input.